# Java Derby Apache Table/View does not exist

Tags: java, mysql, derby

thanks for taking your time to read. I know other questions have been asked that are similar. The problem im having is i have checked all the problems in related questions and still have no solution. I am only trying to select a single column just to see it working but it doesnt matter if i try to select all of them.

Here is my code....

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

public class DBConnection {

    private static final String DRIVER = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver";
    private static String JDBC_URL;

    Connection con;
    public  DBConnection() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        Class.forName(DRIVER).newInstance();

        con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl());
        if(con != null)
        System.out.println("Connection Established");

        Statement st = con.createStatement(); 
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from MOVIES");
        while(rs.next()) { String movieName = rs.getString(1);
            System.out.println(movieName); }

          rs.close();
        con.close();
    }

    private static final String connectionUrl() {
        JDBC_URL = "jdbc:derby:MoviePlayer_JavaFlix;create=true;USER = JavaFlix; password = 123";
        return JDBC_URL;
    }
}
```

I have checked the url path within my database properties and it is identicle. The connection to the database is made. I have even ran the queries within SQL Scrapbook and had no problems with that. My username and passwords are identicle.

Here is the console output...

```
Connection Established
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table/View 'MOVIES' does not exist.
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.wrapInSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.ConnectionChild.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
    at data.source.db.DBConnection.<init>(DBConnection.java:23)
    at data.source.db.Main.main(Main.java:8)
Caused by: ERROR 42X05: Table/View 'MOVIES' does not exist.
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.FromBaseTable.bindTableDescriptor(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.FromBaseTable.bindNonVTITables(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.FromList.bindTables(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.SelectNode.bindNonVTITables(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.DMLStatementNode.bindTables(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.DMLStatementNode.bind(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.CursorNode.bindStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepMinion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepare(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.conn.GenericLanguageConnectionContext.prepareInternalStatement(Unknown Source)
    ... 4 more
```

Here is my database location...

[image]

Here is my folder path...
C:\Users\Banan\eclipse-workspace\MoviePlayer_JavaFlix

I think i may have found some issue that may be causing the problem...

When i run `st.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE movies (ID INT PRIMARY KEY, movie_name VARCHAR(50))")`

A table is created...

[image]

However, i can not select, insert or do anything with this.

Comment: Remove the `create=true` attribute and try running again. I'm wondering if you're pointing to the wrong location and apache is creating a new MoviePlayer_JavaFlix blank database, with no MOVIES table in it to select from?

Comment: If that's the case, you should include the full path to your database, or make sure you're executing your java application from the same folder containing the database. For example: `JDBC_URL = "jdbc:derby:c:/myprojects/whateverpath/MoviePlayer_JavaFlix;USER = JavaFlix; password = 123";`

Comment: Thanks you for your replies. I have removed the create=true and still have the same issue. My database location is within my application when i look in JDBC Connection Properties and i have tried using the full path.

Comment: Did you try making your connection code like this: `JDBC_URL = "jdbc:derby:C:/Users/Banan/eclipse-workspace/MoviePlayer_JavaFlix/Databases;USER = JavaFlix; password = 123";` .   Notice the separater in the path is forward slashes `/` not backslashes `\`

Comment: Yes i have changed seperators. I even disconnected my database witin the data explorer tab. I have checked that there are no duplicates in other folders. Ran a debug to check the connection and it is still pointing to the intended folder. Had a good check that the tables actually exist and ran queries to check again.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of viewing your data/table in the IDE? I'm wondering if you need to prefix the tablename with a schema or something? Like `select * from JavaFlix.MOVIES;` . Or if the table is case sensitive. Does it appear as `MOVIES` or is actually `"movies"` or `"Movies"`?

Comment: I have added a little more info and found some issue

Comment: Try to change your query to `select * from APP.MOVIES;` You may need to grant permission to your user too but I'm not sure about that.  `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON TABLE APP.MOVIES TO JavaFlix`

Comment: Ok first, thank you for your help Nicholas. It is working now and allows me to manipulate the db from within my code. Everything i have read or watched does not point out that you have to specify the file path within the schema to allow any type of query to run e.g. APP.MOVIES. My SQL is not the best but it does what i need. I didn't need to grant any permissions. Thank you :)

Comment: I'm glad it's working!  Yes the schema prefix is only needed if your tables aren't created in the users default schema. When you connect as user JavaFlix, if you created your MOVIES table in the JavaFlix schema instead of the APP schema, you would be able to do just `select * from MOVIES;` and see the data.

Answer (score 1):

You're connecting as `JavaFlix` user, so that is also the default schema you are selecting from.  The table you are trying to access is in the APP schema.  You need to prefix your tablename with the schema, such as

`SELECT * FROM APP.MOVIES`

Or alternatively, create a synonym such as

`CREATE SYNONYM MOVIES FOR APP.MOVIES`

After which you should just be able to do `SELECT * FROM MOVIES` from your schema.